# What is the alternative to using the deprecated 'var' in this example code?

Tags: solidity

Example code is shown below. I am just starting out and have seen examples in the declaration of the specific types instead however I don't know how to do this in the context of a `struct`.

```
contract Courses is Owned {

    struct Instructor {
        uint age;
        string fName;
        string sName;
    }

    mapping (address => Instructor) instructors;
    address[] public instructorAccts;

    function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string _fName, string _sName) onlyOwner public {

        var instructor = instructors[_address];

        instructor.age = _age;
        instructor.fName = _fName;
        instructor.sName = _sName;

        instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Instructor storage instructor = instructors[_address];`

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

As the mapping declaration indicates, `instructors` maps to the `Instructor` type.

```
Instructor storage instructor = instructors[_address];
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I got confused by the syntax in the tutorial I'm following.